# How to debug FileSystemWatcher c#

Tags: filesystemwatcher

Can someone explain how I debug this?

I have built a windows service which monitors a folder and when a file is created in that folder, it moves that newly created file to another folder. Pretty simple and works. I am trying to pad it out now with out features and I'm starting to get generic IOExpections thrown in event viewer, so I want to try and debug. But the issue I am having is when to create the new file in the directory during debugging.

This is my code so far

which line should I stop at during stepping through, place my new file in the directory and then continue debugging so that it picks up the created file?

```
public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        string pathToWatch = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectoryToWatch"];

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = pathToWatch;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileCreated);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void FileCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dt = File.GetCreationTime(e.FullPath);
            File.Move(e.FullPath.ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectoryToMoveTo"] + e.Name + dt.ToString());
            LogEvent($"New file found and moved \n {e.FullPath.ToString()}");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            LogEvent(ex.ToString());
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by adding a breakpoint inside the function FileCreated.

I suggest you add a breakpoint at

> DateTime dt = File.GetCreationTime(e.FullPath);

When you create a new file in the directory being watched, the FileSystemWatcher gets notified and the function FileCreated is called.

I also suggest you to log the destination path for your move. Just to make sure it's a valid path.

Comment: Hi, what I am struggling with is making the FileCreated event trigger during debug. I don't know when I should be placing a new file in the folder as I am stepping through the code.

Comment: You don't have to do anything extra to trigger that event. Just create a file after the initialization is done. But you can't reach that event directly by stepping through.

Try doing this:
1. Add a breakpoint in the beginning of FileCreated.
2. Run your application
3. Create a file in the folder being watched
4. You should now see the control reach your breakpoint. Now you can step through your code from this point.